# Iterating through json factory cycling through results with ng-repeat using nganimate/gsap to update view

Tags: angularjs, timeout, directive, animate.css, gsap

I have in separate files, a  json factory bringing in quotes, a controller to utilize the factory as a service, and a directive with a template to update the view.

quoteFactory.js

```
var quoteFactory = angular.module('quoteFactory', []);

quoteApp.factory('famous', function ($http) {
  return {
    list: function(callback){
  $http.get('famous.json').success(callback);
    }
   };
 });
```

quoteControllers.js

```
var quoteControllers = angular.module('quoteControllers', []);

quoteControllers.controller('QuoteCtrl', function ($scope,$timeout, famous){
  famous.list(function(quotes) {
console.log(quotes);
$scope.quotes = quotes;
});
});
```

quote-div.html

```
    <div ng-controller="QuoteCtrl">
      <div class="container-fluid base" id="base">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="famous in quotes">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <br><br><br>

    <blockquote class="base bounceIn">

  <h2>&#8220;{{ famous.quote }}&#8221;</h2>

  <br>
  <footer>{{ famous.author }} via<cite title="Source Title">{{ famous.source }}</cite>                  </footer>
</blockquote>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</div>
```

and finally, famous.json

```
[
 {
"id": 1,
"quote": "Without music, life would be a mistake.",
"author":"Friedrich Nietzsche",
"source":"Twilight of the Idols"
 },
 {
"id": 2,
"quote": "What goes on inside is just too fast and huge and all interconnected for     words to do more than barely sketch the outlines of at most one tiny little part of it at     any given instant.",
"author":"David Foster Wallace",
"source":"Oblivion"
 },
 {
 "id": 3,
 "quote": "I am so clever that sometimes I don't understand a single word of what I am saying.",
"author":"Oscar Wilde",
"source":"The Happy Prince and Other Stories"
 },
 {
 "id": 4,
 "quote": "If you were half as funny as you think you are, you'd be twice as funny as you are now.",
 "author":"Cassandra Clare",
 "source":"City of Bones"
 },
 {
 "id": 5,
 "quote": "If you want to know what a man's like, take a good look at how he treats his inferiors, not his equals.",
  "author":"J.K. Rowling",
  "source":"Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire"
 }
 ]
```

what I would like to happen is to update the views through $timeout, upon view ready, view loaded or angular document ready, cycle through my json in an infinite loop to display the quotes, using animate.css or gsap (TweenMax) to manage the transitions. included are the factory, controller, app, and directive codes, as well as [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/romeski/jW2jV/) to illustrate my work.

UPDATE!

I did some research and realized what I wanted was a slider. I found a plugin based off of a tutorial, and decided to implement. what is happening is that I am receiving these errors:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at sliderFunc (http://localhost/romecode/assets/js/quoteDirective.js:34:10)
at link (http://localhost/romecode/assets/js/quoteDirective.js:40:3)


TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at Object.fn (http://localhost/romecode/assets/js/quoteDirective.js:22:16)
```

here is my new quote directive

```
  var quoteDirective = angular.module('quoteDirective', []);

  quoteDirective.directive('quoteDirective', [function (famous, $timeout) {
    return {
    priority: 0,
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        quotes:"="
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, famous) {
        scope.currentIndex=0;

    scope.next=function(){
        scope.currentIndex<scope.quotes.length-1?scope.currentIndex++:scope.currentIndex=0;
    };

    scope.prev=function(){
        scope.currentIndex>0?scope.currentIndex--      :scope.currentIndex=scope.quotes.length-1;
    };

    scope.$watch('currentIndex',function(){
        scope.quotes.forEach(function(quotes){
            quotes.visible=false;
        });
        scope.quotes[scope.currentIndex].visible=true;
        console.log(scope.quotes);
    });

    /* Start: For Automatic slideshow*/

    var timer;

    var sliderFunc = function(){
        timer=$timeout(function(){
            scope.next();
            timer=$timeout(sliderFunc,5000);
        },5000);
    };

    sliderFunc();

    scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
        $timeout.cancel(timer);
    });

    /* End : For Automatic slideshow*/

    },
    templateUrl: 'quote-div.html'
    }
   }]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.